# Difficulty accessing Heroku process.env variables outside of index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, environment-variables

I have an app on heroku that I am trying to use heroku:config variables with. When I log into heroku through command line ('heroku login') and then type 'heroku config' I am able to see a variable called MY_EMAIL which contains 'myemail@mail.com". However, I made a program entitled index.js containing the following code:

```
console.log("Test line 1");
console.log(process.env.MY_EMAIL);
```

I ran this program by typing:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Adding process.env test"
git push heroku master
```

I then ran this by typing 'node index.js' into the command line in the folder containing index.js while logged into heroku. It prints:

```
Test line 1
undefined
```

Any ideas why MY_EMAIL may not be being accessed? Thanks.

Comment: because the variable is defined for the heroku environment (their server) while you're running it on your own machine.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this so that I can test it? Thanks

Comment: How are you running the server on your machine?

Comment: I can type 'node index.js'? is that what you mean?